# Can't get my maze wall collisions to work c#

Tags: c#, collision, maze

Im trying to get the main mechanics for a maze game working but i cant figure this out.

I want it to jump the character back if they hit the rectangle but it doesn't seem to do so and you just end up stuck.

here is my code:

```
Texture2D txr;
    Rectangle rect;
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 velocity;

    public player(Texture2D texture)
    {
        txr = texture;
        position = new Vector2(100, 100);
        rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, txr.Width, txr.Height);
    }

    public void update(Rectangle wall, GameTime gt)
    {
        MoveIfPossible(gt, wall);

        KeyboardState keys = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            velocity = new Vector2(0, -1);
        else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            velocity = new Vector2(0, 1);
        else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            velocity = new Vector2(-1, 0);
        else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            velocity = new Vector2(1, 0);
        else
            velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);

        rect.X = (int)position.X;
        rect.Y = (int)position.Y;

    }

    private void UpdatePositionBasedOnMovement(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        position += velocity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 4;
    }

    private void MoveIfPossible(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle wall)
    {
        Vector2 oldPosition = position;

        UpdatePositionBasedOnMovement(gameTime);
        if (rect.Intersects(wall))
        {
            position = oldPosition;
        }
    }
```

If anyone knows why it doesnt work please let me know!!

Im sorry to say that these changes have not fixed the fact that the player gets stuck on the wall. Here is the rest of my code if it helps
Game1

```
 KeyboardState curr_keys;
    Rectangle wall_rect;
    Texture2D wall;
    player player;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // wall
        wall_rect = new Rectangle(200, 100, 100, 100);
        player = new player(Content.Load<Texture2D>("maze_rect_border"));
        wall = Content.Load<Texture2D>("maze_rect_border");
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        curr_keys = Keyboard.GetState();
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();
        if (curr_keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        player.update(wall_rect, gameTime);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(wall, wall_rect, Color.White);
        player.draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

player

```
Texture2D txr;
    Rectangle rect;
    Vector2 position;

    public player(Texture2D texture)
    {
        txr = texture;
        position = new Vector2(100, 100);
        rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, txr.Width, txr.Height);
    }

    public void update(Rectangle wall, GameTime gt)
    {
        KeyboardState keys = Keyboard.GetState();

        Vector2 velocity;
        if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            velocity = new Vector2(0, -1);
        else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            velocity = new Vector2(0, 1);
        else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            velocity = new Vector2(-1, 0);
        else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            velocity = new Vector2(1, 0);
        else
            velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);

        Move(gt, wall, velocity);

        rect.X = (int)position.X;
        rect.Y = (int)position.Y;
    }

    private void Move(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle wall, Vector2 velocity)
    {
        Vector2 oldPosition = position;

        position += velocity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 4;
        if (rect.Intersects(wall))
        {
            position = oldPosition;
        }
    }


    public void draw(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        sb.Draw(txr, position, Color.White);
    }
```

Thank you for your help so far, any other ideas?

Comment: When you intersect the wall you are returning the same position you started with.  To move backwards multiply velocity by -1 and move.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are utilizing the velocity vector before it has been initialized. I'm not sure what result that would produce. I think the root cause is that you have velocity as a class variable, when it really should be local instead.

I would change MoveIfPossible to be after velocity is initialized. I would also change velocity to be a local variable. Here's a summary of the changes with comments to track what I did.

I would also get rid of the UpdatePositionBasedOnMovement method. I'm not sure it adds anything in this case other than obfuscating what you are trying to do in this case.

```
Texture2D txr;
Rectangle rect;
Vector2 position;
//Vector2 velocity;

public player(Texture2D texture)
{
    txr = texture;
    position = new Vector2(100, 100);
    rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, txr.Width, txr.Height);
}

public void update(Rectangle wall, GameTime gt)
{
    //MoveIfPossible(gt, wall);     // the velocity vector was not set when this was being called

    KeyboardState keys = Keyboard.GetState();

    Vector2 velocity;  // Change this to local
    if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        velocity = new Vector2(0, -1);
    else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        velocity = new Vector2(0, 1);
    else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        velocity = new Vector2(-1, 0);
    else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        velocity = new Vector2(1, 0);
    else
        velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);

    MoveIfPossible(gt, wall, velocity); // Pass vector as a parameter, if it's not needed elsewhere, keep it local

    rect.X = (int)position.X;
    rect.Y = (int)position.Y;

}

// private void UpdatePositionBasedOnMovement(GameTime gameTime)
// {
    // position += velocity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 4;
// }

private void MoveIfPossible(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle wall, Vector2 velocity)
{
    Vector2 oldPosition = position;

    //UpdatePositionBasedOnMovement(gameTime);          // Don't think this is adding anything with just one line of code
    position += velocity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 4;
    if (rect.Intersects(wall))
    {
        position = oldPosition;
    }
}
```

Cleaning up and removing all comments, I would personally write/name it this way:

```
Texture2D txr;
Rectangle rect;
Vector2 position;

public player(Texture2D texture)
{
    txr = texture;
    position = new Vector2(100, 100);
    rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, txr.Width, txr.Height);
}

public void update(Rectangle wall, GameTime gt)
{
    KeyboardState keys = Keyboard.GetState();

    Vector2 velocity;
    if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        velocity = new Vector2(0, -1);
    else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        velocity = new Vector2(0, 1);
    else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        velocity = new Vector2(-1, 0);
    else if (keys.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        velocity = new Vector2(1, 0);
    else
        velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);

    Move(gt, wall, velocity);

    rect.X = (int)position.X;
    rect.Y = (int)position.Y;
}

private void Move(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle wall, Vector2 velocity)
{
    Vector2 oldPosition = position;

    position += velocity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 4;
    if (rect.Intersects(wall))
    {
        position = oldPosition;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this wasn't all of the code. My gut tells me it would be better to move the Vector2 position into a local as well, although without insight into the rect.Intersects() method I don't have enough information to say for sure. Or more likely it seems like it should be a property of the rectangle class itself.

In general I would default to not using class variables. Start off by not making something a class variable. You can always go back and change that if you find a reason, but local variables simplify code. Simple code has less bugs.

Comment: Unfortunatly this has not fixed the issue so I have added the rest of the code to my original question, please take a look